# Getting error while deploying using flyctl (flyio)

Tags: node.js, heroku, command-line-interface, vercel

On my heroku app, the free dyno hours are over so i am trying to deploy the web app on https://fly.io/

I have installed flyctl and signed up too but now I am getting this error: incorrect function function

[image: flyctl error by abhinavkashyap061]

Complete error below:

```
$ flyctl launch
Creating app in C:\Users\Abhinav\Desktop\todolist-abhinavkashyap061
Scanning source code
Detected a NodeJS app
Using the following build configuration:
        Builder: heroku/buildpacks:20
? App Name (leave blank to use an auto-generated name): Error Incorrect function.
```

Comment: As you try out a new service, you could also consider Render (where I work) and see which works better for you. Migration docs: https://render.com/docs/migrate-from-heroku and here are quickstarts for Express: https://render.com/docs/deploy-node-express-app and Hapi: https://render.com/docs/deploy-node-hapi-app

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Switched to PowerShell and it worked.

https://community.fly.io/t/launching-node-app-error-incorrect-function/6963

Comment: Any idea why switching to Powershell helped?